# Grub won't show on startup, no matter what I try

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi, windows-10

I recently, for fun, tried to take an old computer, format it, and install a dual OS (Windows 10 Home and Ubuntu 18.04) I successfully got both of them installed and running, but to switch between them, I have to use the device's boot selector instead of Ubuntu's convenient grub interface. It does show, but not on boot-up. See the image below for the exact boot order.

[image: boot manager diagram]
<sup>(Click image to enlarge)</sup>

No matter what I do, I can't get it to show grub on boot-up. I've tried changing the EFI within Ubuntu (it resets after restart), changing within Windows (no option), changing from BIOS (no option), reinstalling grub like 3 times (no effect) and everything else. Can someone please help me get grub to show on first startup?

Here is the output of `sudo parted -l` :

```
Model: ATA ST750LM022 HN-M7 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 750GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags: 
Number  Start   End    Size    File system     Name                          Flags
 1      1049kB  524MB  523MB   ntfs            Basic data partition          hidden, diag
 2      524MB   629MB  105MB   fat32           EFI system partition          boot, esp
 3      629MB   646MB  16.8MB                  Microsoft reserved partition  msftres
 4      646MB   393GB  393GB   ntfs            Basic data partition          msftdata
 5      393GB   744GB  351GB   ext4
 6      744GB   750GB  6328MB  linux-swap(v1)
```

I checked, both Windows 10 and Ubuntu 18.04 are in UEFI.

Comment: Are both installed in same boot mode, or both UEFI? And is Windows fast start up off, so grub2's os-prober can see the Windows install? then all you should need is `sudo update-grub` and then when grub has both entries it will automatically show.  http://askubuntu.com/questions/843153/ubuntu-16-showing-windows-10-partitions  If not post this link to details: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info

Comment: I did turn off fast boot. I forgot to mention it, but I tried everything I physically could. I'll try that command tomorrow, I need sleep.

Comment: I think you need to also disable hibernate, then re-enable ubuntu as the default uefi boot. Otherwise when windows tries to hibernate, it will change the uefi settings.

Comment: Please boot into Ubuntu and [edit] your post with the output of `sudo parted -l`

Comment: pim, When i disabled hibernate it didn't even give me an option for fast boot, so i assumed it was disabled automatically.

Comment: oldfred, I did that command but it still booted to windows.